# XMLHttpRequest is timeout before response is arrived

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am calling one cgi script which takes 50 minutes to send response.I need to keep my xhr alive till the response comes from that cgi.
How to do that ?
it seems like after certain default time request automatically timed out.

Comment: Try optimizing that cgi script, 50 minutes is too much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
xhr.timeout = 10000;
xhr.ontimeout = timeoutFired;
```

for this purpose

Comment: timeoutFired will be your function, which will be called once timeout happens (i.e, if you want to ignore your request after certain period of time, then you can make use of this function)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be doing this inline with the request.  The alternative is to submit your request as a job to some back end process/thread/message queue and store a reference so that you can access the results, e.g. in a database or even a file once the processing is complete.

Until the results are available, you could show some 'updating' text or spinning icon to let the user know something is happening.

For that length of time I wouldn't rely on an open HTTP connection.

Comment: Thnx for reply but any how I need to do this as per requirement.Actually user should not be able to do anything until that cgi call is completed.

Comment: @adn295: For this, just show an loading image (disabling the background, so that no operation cab be done), once the request has been sent (check for xmlhttprequest request sent code) and remove that image once the response is received.